# How to calculate distances between stitching vias for RF lines?

Tags: pcb-design, pcb-antenna, via-hole, stitching

I have a query concerning the stitching of vias for RF lines and board fencing. According to the application note, it is recommended that the distance between vias should fall within the range of one-tenth to one-twentieth of the wavelength.
[image]
For an RF frequency of 868MHz on a PCB with an effective relative permittivity (εr_eff) of 4.4, the guided wavelength is approximately 0.16476888062999867 meters.

[image]

Following the recommendation, the distance between vias should ideally be between 16mm and 8.2mm, which seems quite significant.

Could you please advise on any potential errors in my approach or provide guidance on how to accurately calculate via distances for RF lines? Additionally, are there any recommendations for via sizes that I should consider?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lambda/10 rule of thumb is to provide a certain amount of attenuation at the frequency of interest. I forget exactly what that attenuation level is, but if you need more attenuation you either space the vias closer together or you put in a second, staggered row of vias like the graphic shows. It all comes down to how much attenuation, or isolation do you need.

At higher frequencies say above 10 GHz, it may be difficult to achieve the attenuation needed because you may not be able to place vias in a single row as close as needed because of manufacturing constraints.  This is when a second row of vias, staggered from the first, help.

**Added Examples**

One example where attenuation, or isolation on the order of 35 dB is needed is in multi-channel RF/microwave assemblies, where isolation between channels is needed to meet performance requirements.  Some of this isolation can be achieved through separation.  But many RF modules are very high density and adequate isolation through physical separation cannot be achieved without growing the module.  Hence the use of stitching vias.

Comment: Attenuation, to what? -- It may be worth highlighting under what circumstances such the rule becomes important (i.e., with nearby traces); and for which without, the trace could just as well be microstrip, at somewhat different width.

Answer (score 2):

The equation is a "rule of thumb" as a *maximum spacing* between vias to prevent weird modes. You can **reduce** the distance between vias but it's not advised to **increase** distance.

You're at really a low frequency so your calculated "minimum spacing" is quite large. For mmW designs, for example, spacing starts to get close to design rules of PCB design.

Answer (score 1):

Your arithmetic is basically correct, 16 mm is a reasonable maximum spacing for signals < 1 GHz.

You could put the vias closer than 8 mm if you want to, it's just that you don't need to.